# Asterisk usage in variable naming

Tags: syntax, asterisk

I came across a solution to reserving a C-style String. Here is the code:

```
void reserve(char *str) {
     char * end = str;
     char tmp;
     if (str) {
         while(*end) {
             ++end;
         }
         --end;
         while (str < end) {
            tmp = *str;
            *str++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
         }
     }
}
```

Question:
What does the *str mean as char type in this function, and how about * end ?

Comment: I can guarantee you that this syntax is not Java.

Comment: This is C code, not Java. `char *` is how C works with strings.

Comment: And I think you mean "reverse", not "reserve".

Answer (score 1):

That isn't Java. You can't begin variables in Java with '*'.

Comment: It kinda answers the question, but it might be worth expanding the answer to make it seem less like a comment.